# Using .change() function to auto-submit form on checkbox change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a bit of a long question so please bear with me guys.

I needed to make a form submit automatically when a checkbox was ticked. So far I have the code below and **it works perfectly**. The form must submit when the check box is either checked or unchecked. There is some PHP that reads a database entry and shows the appropriate status (checked or unchecked) on load.

```
<form method="post" id="edituser" class="user-forms" action="--some php here--">
    <input class="lesson" value="l101" name="flesson" type="checkbox" />
</form>
<script>
    $('.lesson').change(function() {
        $('.user-forms').submit(); 
    });
</script>
```

However, when I introduce a fancy checkbox script which turns checkboxes into sliders it no longer works. The checkbox jQuery script is below:

```
<script src="'.get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/jquery/checkboxes.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type=checkbox]").tzCheckbox({labels:["Enable","Disable"]});
    });
</script>
```

The contents of the checkboxes.js called to above is as follows:

```
(function($){
$.fn.tzCheckbox = function(options){

    // Default On / Off labels:

    options = $.extend({
        labels : ['ON','OFF']
    },options);

    return this.each(function(){
        var originalCheckBox = $(this),
            labels = [];

        // Checking for the data-on / data-off HTML5 data attributes:
        if(originalCheckBox.data('on')){
            labels[0] = originalCheckBox.data('on');
            labels[1] = originalCheckBox.data('off');
        }
        else labels = options.labels;

        // Creating the new checkbox markup:
        var checkBox = $('<span>',{
            className   : 'tzCheckBox '+(this.checked?'checked':''),
            html:   '<span class="tzCBContent">'+labels[this.checked?0:1]+
                    '</span><span class="tzCBPart"></span>'
        });

        // Inserting the new checkbox, and hiding the original:
        checkBox.insertAfter(originalCheckBox.hide());

        checkBox.click(function(){
            checkBox.toggleClass('checked');

            var isChecked = checkBox.hasClass('checked');

            // Synchronizing the original checkbox:
            originalCheckBox.attr('checked',isChecked);
            checkBox.find('.tzCBContent').html(labels[isChecked?0:1]);
        });

        // Listening for changes on the original and affecting the new one:
        originalCheckBox.bind('change',function(){
            checkBox.click();
        });
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

There is also some CSS that accompanies this script but I am leaving it out as it is not important.

Finally, this is what the jQuery script does to the checkbox:

```
<input id="on_off_on" class="lesson" value="lesson11-1" name="forexadvanced[]" type="checkbox" style="display: none; ">
<span classname="tzCheckBox checked" class=""><span class="tzCBContent">Disable</span><span class="tzCBPart"></span></span>
```

When the checkboxes are changed into sliders the .change() function no longer detects the change in the checkboxes status.

How can I make the .change() function work or is their an alternative function I can use?

Comment: 1) Welcome to StackOverflow!  
2) Next time when you are gonna dump a buncha code like this, use jsfiddle so we can see what's going on

Comment: +1 for cleaning up your question yourself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin changes your checkboxes to span elements and hides the actual checkboxes themselves. Thus, when you click on them, nothing happens. Since span elements don't have onchange events, you can't bind change events to these.

However, span elements do have click events, meaning that you could instead bind a click event to the generated spans, using Firebug or Chrome Debugger to locate the correct element to bind to.

Your click-handler can then take the same action your change event would normally take if the plugin weren't being used.

Here is an example:

**HTML (Source):**

```
<!-- This is a checkbox BEFORE running the code that transforms the checkboxes 
   into sliders -->
<li>
    <label for="pelda1">Opció 1:</label>
    <input class="pelda" type="checkbox" id="pelda1" name="pelda1" />
</li>
```

**HTML (Generated From Chrome Debugger):**

NOTE:  This is the generated HTML after running the JavaScript that converts checkboxes to sliders! You must bind your click event *AFTER* this code is generated.

```
<li>
    <label for="pelda1">Option 1:</label>

    <!-- The hidden checkbox -->
    <input class="pelda" type="checkbox" id="pelda1" name="pelda1" style="display: none; " />

    <!-- the "checked" class on the span gets changed when you toggle the slider 
         if it's there, then it's checked. This is what you're users are actually
         changing. 
    -->
    <span class="tzCheckBox checked">
        <span class="tzCBContent">active</span>
        <span class="tzCBPart"></span>
    </span>
</li>
```

**JavaScript:**

NOTE: This must be bound **AFTER** converting the checkboxes to sliders. If you try it before, the HTML won't yet exist in the DOM!

```
$('.tzCheckBox').click(function() {

    // alert the value of the hidden checkbox
    alert( $('#pelda1').attr("checked") );

    // submit your form here
});
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. I added this code -->$('.user-forms').submit();<-- underneath // submit your form here. Is this correct?

Comment: Try using the Id. It's possible that -- since class selectors can retrieve collections -- it's expecting you to be more specific and say index 0. Also, please be more specific other than "it doesn't work". Are there error messages in your debugger?

Comment: Hmmm. Seems the class should work after all. You have another problem in your code. Are you sure the click event is even being called? Put an alert in there or a console.info so you can see what's going on. Also, keep in mind that these are examples. You'll need to make sure the classes on **your** checkbox spans match the selector for the click handler... which it looks like it does...

Comment: Also, try binding the click event in your debugger JavaScript console. If the click event submits after doing that, then you're possibly binding the click event **before** the conversion in your actual code.

Comment: First of all I just want to say thanks for your help. This solution seems to be the most efficient.... but I think I have realised the problem. The class field does not have tzCheckBox in it. The field with tzCheckBox is classname="tzCheckBox checked"

Comment: @forex4noobs - Good eye! To make sure we're on the same page, that attribute should be class= not classname=.  If you fix that, my bet is things will start to fall closer into place :)  classname is not actually a valid HTML attribute and should be removed completely.

Comment: Thanks, I found a different script as the one I was using inserted the bad classname attribute. I used your code with the new script and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Listen for change like this:

```
 $('.lesson').bind("tzCheckboxChange",function() {
      $('.user-forms').submit(); 
 });
```

Modify the plugin by adding the line:

```
 $(originalCheckBox).trigger("tzCheckboxChange");
```

after

```
 checkBox.find('.tzCBContent').html(labels[isChecked?0:1]);
```

This way, anytime you use this plugin, you can listen for **tzCheckboxChange** instead of just **change**. 
I don't really know what's going on with the plugin, but seems kinda funky for it to be listening for a change event when it would only be fired through trigger (unless it doesn't hide the original checkbox).

Comment: Thanks, this seems to half work. When the checkbox starts unchecked this will submit the form properly but when it starts of as checked this wont submit properly. When the checkbox starts as checked and I try to uncheck it the page refreshed but it remains checked.